# Issue with custom exception

Tags: java, exception

I have created a custom exception `xyException` by creating a `.java` file with the same name. I am showing this exception when user violates a condition. This works perfectly fine on my local machine. However, when I put the code on server, I get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xyException
at A.<init>(A.java:24)
at mainClass.<init>(mainClass.java:27)
at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:251)
```

Interestingly all the above errors are at lines where I am calling the default constructor of other classes.

```
line:24:object_B = new B();
line:27:mainClass A list = new A();
line:251:mainClass mainClass M = new mainClass();
```

The code was working perfectly fine before I added this exception.

```
public class xyException extends Exception
{
    public stonesRemoveException(String msg)
    {
       super(msg);
    }
}
void someFunc()(//parameters) 
{
    //code
    try
    {
       if(//condition)
       {
           throw new xyException("error" + some_variable + "string");
       }
       else if(//condition)
       {
           throw new xyException("error" + some_variable + "string");
       }
     }
     catch(xyException e)
     {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(error);
        someFunc(//parameters) 
     }

 }
```

However, I have no clue where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you add the exception class to the server ?

Comment: you need to add the excception on the path of the server as well.
but, if I may ask: what on earth are you trying to do here:
public xyException(//arguments) {
        if(x>y)
        {
            //code
        }
        else if //condition
        {
            //code
        }
        else
            //code
    }

Comment: @fxm-I added the class to the server of course.

Comment: @Stultuske - that is some sort of game exception or u can say rules that I am handling over there.

Comment: yes, that I can see, but why would you have any "rules" in the constructor of an Exception?
why would you put rules inside an Exception at all?

Comment: @Stultuske - I am getting your point :-) that is what Vishrant also highlighted. Cheers!!

Comment: @Stultuske - I am still facing the same issue. Edited the above post with my updated code.

Comment: seems to me like you still haven't added that exception to the path of the server you're running it on

Comment: @Stultuske-I just need to put my files on a server, and run a batch command to execute it. Server takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your exception class like:

```
public class xyException extends Exception {

    public xyException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

Use your below condition in your business logic to raise user defined exception, not in User defined class.

```
if(x>y)
{
    //code
}
else if //condition
{
    //code
}
else
    //code
```

This is because you will have to call `super(msg);` and `Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor`.

So you can not add `if` condition before `super(msg)` call if you try to add `if` condition by removing `super();` then your class will be no more an `Exception` class

Comment: I got your point. So business logic remains in the core class, and if a violation happens then it will throw an exception with a message, which I will pass to xyException class, isnt it?

Comment: yes. you can use like `throw new xyException("Your exception message");`

Comment: yes I just did it. PFB my solution. The message does not seem to go inside the exception class?

Comment: use `e.printStackTrace();` OR `e.getMessage();` to get passed message.

Comment: Issue is still the same on the server though. No change

Comment: @MrCoder have you added your newly created user defined exception class while deploying in server. if you have declared it in other project you will have to link it, either by creating a jar and adding it into your application.

Comment: why would I need to do that? This is just another .java file isn't it?

Comment: @Vishrant- I just need to put my files on a server, and run a batch command to execute it. Server takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your exception class is integrated in the files your are deploying on your server.

Comment: yes it is integrated. However, still the same issue.